# unable to load google maps with google api

Tags: c#, google-maps, model-view-controller, windows

I am creating a window app in which i want to show user location to the user(as per current location which i am getting from latitude and longitude)

i am calling a mvc app in i am fetching user data and generating user location,

here is how my code looks

```
    public ViewMap()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewMapURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ViewMapURL"];
    }


    private void ViewMap_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (vehicleNo == null)
        {
            Map(CurrentTrip.VehicleNo, CurrentTrip.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            Map(vehicleNo, 0);

        }
    }


    private void Map(string VehicleNo, long tripId)
    {

        string address = ViewMapURL + "?back=true&close=true&vehicleno="+VehicleNo+"&tripid="+tripId;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return;
        if (address.Equals("about:blank")) return;

        if (!address.StartsWith("http://") &&
            !address.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            address = "http://" + address;
        }
        try
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(address));
        }
        catch (System.UriFormatException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

the problem is,

this code is working fine in some machines and maps are not loading in other machines(sometimes showing me error that you are using a browser that is not supported by google maps, and sometimes it is showing just blank screen),

all my pc's have internet explorer 11 but still i am getting this error,

what could be the possible reason?

Comment: whats the error you are getting

Comment: @Musab edited my question

Comment: i had a similar issue with IE when the compatibility mode was on